# Why can't we define an anonymous class in place for inheritance?

Tags: c++, standards

```
class MyClass : SomeFeatureGeneratedByTemplate<MyClass>
```

Template offers much convenience to add a feature to our class just by inheriting a instantiated class template.

However, sometimes the feature may get too complicated to be implemented by template, where macro might be the only choice.

```
    MACRO_TO_GENERATE_COMPLICATED_FEATURE(MyClass) 
   /* Might be expanded to 
    #ifndef MYCLASS_FEATURE_CLASS
    #define MYCLASS_FEATURE_CLASS
        class MyClassFeature { ... };
    #endif
   */
   class MyClass : MyClassFeature
```

I wonder if the following syntax would simplify this:
allow to define a anonymous class just in place

```
class MyClass : class { ... }, class{ ... }
```

Therefore, the above code could be rewritten as:

```
class MyClass : MACRO_GEN_FEATURE(MyClass)
```

APPEND:

Q: Why don't I embed the code just inside class?

A: 
1. This feature should be explicit and exposed to user. When they generating docs, derived class is easy to discover :`class A: FEATURE1(A), FEATURE2(A)` while embedded macro isn't. Although an empty class could be derived to achieve our goal(e.g `class A: FEATURE1(A)//just derive predefined struct FEATURE1_EMPTY{};`), apparently it is not a perfect solution.

2. Sometimes we even needn't to get *any* member from the class generated by macro, but that class has to include member to provide some function(e.g `static_assert` with some helper class templates).
3. Complete specialization of a nested class template is not allowed, which prevents me from using nested class to avoid namespace conflicts mentioned in 2).

**I know that this is illegal right now, but why is this not allowed in C++ standard?**

Comment: What would the point of such a thing be? You want to write a base class, write a base class.

Comment: It seems to me that only the class defining it would be able to inherit from it making it redundant.

Comment: Why is it not allowed? How about why should it be allowed?

Comment: What prevents you from expanding `MACRO_GEN_FEATURE` directly inside `MyClass`?

Answer (score 5):

Because neither Bjarne (in the 1980s) nor anybody on the ISO committee (1990s—now) saw a need for this. I've never seen a need for it until this macro hackery today.

Here's how a language is developed:

- Start with nothing
- Feature is needed? Add it!

Here's how a language is *not* developed:

- Start with every possible feature, in an ∞-pages long standard
- Feature not needed? Remove it!

Answer (score 5):

```
class MyClass : class { /* CONTENT */ } {
  // HERE
};
```

What ever you would put where `CONTENT` is, would be only used or even accessible from the class `MyClass`, so it can equally well be written where the `HERE` stands.

If you want to "organise" the contents of a single class, you could use "nested" classes to enhance encapsulation:

```
class Thing {
  class SomeSubThing {} subthing;
};
```

Though whether this useful or even recommendable is highly depended of the actual case and probably highly subjective.